# Onsen-UI上でオーバーライドした$exceptionHandlerが実行されない

Tags: monaca, onsen-ui, angularjs, cordova

お世話になります
onsen-ui+angularJSを使用してアプリケーションを作成したところ、オーバーライドしたAngularJSの$exceptionHandlerが実行されたり、されなかったりするという現象が発生しました。
いろいろ調べたのですが、法則性が見つからず原因が特定できません。

代表的なものとして、通常の例外は$exceptionHandlerがキャッチしてくれるのですが、
 ons.ready内で発生した例外は$exceptionHandlerでキャッチしてくれません。

```
// オーバーライドした$exceptionHandler
(function () {
    "use strict";    
    angular.module('App')
        .factory('$exceptionHandler', ['$window', function ($window) {
            return function (exception) {
                $window.alert(exception);
            };
        }]);
}());
```

```
// オーバーライドした$exceptionHandlerがキャッチしてくれるケース
angular.module('App').controller(
    'ExceptionController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        throw new Error("ErrorTest");
}]);
```

```
// オーバーライドした$exceptionHandlerがキャッチしてくれないケース
angular.module('App').controller(
    'ExceptionController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        ons.ready(function () {
            throw new Error("ErrorTest");
    });
}]);
```

このほかにも、ons-navigatorタグで指定したng-controllerのコントローラー内で発生した例外はオーバーライドした$exceptionHandlerがキャッチしてくれますが、ons-pageタグで指定したng-controllerのコントローラー内で発生した例外はキャッチしてくれないなどのケースがあります。

原因をご存知の方がおられたらご教授のほどよろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angularのソースにコメントがありました。

> Note, that code executed in event-listeners (even those registered
>   using jqLite's `on`/`bind` methods) does not delegate exceptions to
>   the {@link ng.$exceptionHandler $exceptionHandler} (unless executed
>   during a digest).
>
> If you wish, you can manually delegate exceptions, e.g.
>   `try { ... } catch(e) { $exceptionHandler(e); }`

イベントリスナ内で発生した例外は、digestループ中でない限り$exceptionHandlerには渡らないとあります。`ons.ready()`の引数に指定した関数は`$ons-ready`イベントのハンドラ内で実行されるため、上記のケースにあたります。
ちなみに、`$scope.$apply()`で囲むとちゃんとアラートで表示されました。

```
ons.ready(function(){
  $scope.$apply(function() {
    throw 'error';
  });
});
```

`<ons-page>`タグで指定したコントローラ内の例外をキャッチしないという件は、こちらでは再現しませんでした。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
こちらでも$applyを使うことで$exceptionHandlerでキャッチしてくれることを確認しました。

ソースのコメントにそのようなことが書いてあるとは思いもせず、改めて１次情報の重要さを痛感しました。

なおons-pageですが、どうやらコントローラーのインスタンス生成（コンストラクタ関数実行）時に発生した例外を
$exceptionHandlerで拾ってくれないようです。
（インスタンスが完了するまでAngularJSの管理下に置かれない？）

ですので、こちらに関してはインスタンス生成時の処理を見直す、またはお教えいただいた$applyで囲む方法で対処したいと思います。

今回は本当にありがとうございました。

Comment: お役に立てたようで幸いです。問題が解決したということでしたら、ぜひ回答の承認をご検討ください。